# jquery: How can I iterate through the elements of a list from a viewmodel in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, loops, viewmodel

I want to loop through a list of entries in my viewmodel in an ASP.NET MVC project using jQuery.

I tried this:

```
$.each(@Model.Basisdatenliste, function (index, element) {
    console.log("Element #" + index + ": " + element);
});
```

However it does not work - I get an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Checking the page source it looks like this:

```
$.each(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Areas.Mengenplaner.Models.Basisdaten], function (index, element) {
        console.log("Element #" + index + ": " + element);
 });
```

From the "´" on, the code is set as a comment. What am I doing wrong?

My view model class looks like this (sorry for all the German names):

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public List<Basisdaten> Basisdatenliste { get; set; }
    public List<Verkaufsstellen> Verkaufsstellenliste { get; set; }
    public string AuswahlVerkaufsstelle { get; set; }
    public int AuswahlNummer { get; set; }
    public int AuswahlVerkaufsstellennummer { get; set; }
    public float AuswahlMengeInEinheit { get; set; }
    public float AuswahlMengeInKisten { get; set; }
    public float AuswahlVorschlagKisten { get; set; }
    public int AuswahlPLU { get; set; }
    public DateTime Nextdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AuswahlDatum { get; set; }
}
```

`Basisdatenliste` is a model class which looks like this:

```
public class Basisdaten
{
    [DisplayName("PLU")]
    public int nummer { get; set; }
    public string Artikel { get; set; }
    public int Verkaufsstellennummer { get; set; }
    public string Markt { get; set; }

    public int PLU { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Letzter Verkaufstag")]
    public DateTime LetztesDatum { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Einheit { get; set; }
    public double Verkaufsmenge { get; set; }
    public double PacklisteEinheit { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Letzte Packliste")]
    public double PacklisteKisten { get; set; }
    public int AnzahlVerkaeufe { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ErsterVerkaufProdukt { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan LetzterVerkaufProdukt { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ErsterVerkaufAmVerkaufstag { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan LetzterVerkaufAmVerkaufstag { get; set; }
    public double VerkaufszeitGesamt { get; set; }
    public double AnzahlVerkaeufeProStunde { get; set; }
    public double MengeProVerkauf { get; set; }
    public double ZeitZwischenZweiVerkäufen { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Zeitpunkt_ab_dem_Ware_ausverkauft_sein_darf { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Zeitpunkt_ab_dem_Ware_ausverkauft_sein_darfAbzglZeitZwischenZweiVerkaeufen { get; set; }
    
    [DisplayName("Zu wenig Ware?")]
    public bool ZuWenig { get; set; }
   
    public double MengeZuWenig { get; set; }
    public double GebuchterVerlust { get; set; }
    public double VKPreis { get; set; }
    public double AktuelleUmpackmenge { get; set; }
    public double VorigeUmpackmenge { get; set; }
    public int AnzahlBons { get; set; }
    public int DurchschittszahlBonsVierWochen { get; set; }
    public float Planmenge { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What _is_ a viewmodel in this case? jQuery acts on DOM elements or data objects, not representative data structures.

Comment: You would need to JSON-encode the data so that your output would be valid Javascript.

Comment: Depending on your version of c#/MVC:   `var data = '@JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.Basisdatenliste)';` then `$.each(data, ...`

Comment: Thank you! The JSON part is what I was missing. I added JSON.Enxode and it is working now.